How can I set a Discord mute key/button for M3 MacBook Air running Sonoma?
How can I change the dictate (microphone symbol) and focus (moon symbol) function keys to mute and deafen for Discord on a new M3 MacBook Air running Sonoma?
I do not use these keys at all. The only easy option in keyboard settings turns off all of the function keys at the same time, which is not something I want.

To do this you will need to make use of the new hidutil functions (which I believe only work on Apple Silicon models but I have not confirmed) as well as Hammerspoon.
The first step is to add a plist file to 'flip' the two keys to their default f5 and f6 functionality instead of their macOS uses, using apples new hidutil functions. Create a file called ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.local.KeyRemapping.plist and fill it with this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.local.KeyRemapping</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/hidutil</string>
        <string>property</string>
        <string>--set</string>
        <string>{"UserKeyMapping":[
            {
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0xC000000CF,
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0x70000003E
            },
            {
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0x10000009B,
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0x70000003F
            }
        ]}</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

The second step is to use Hammerspoon to translate f5 and f6 into the discord hotkeys for mute and deafen, which are command shift m and d respectively. Put this code in your ~/.hammerspoon/init.lua:
-- this function checks if discord is open, and if it is it sends it (while in the background or in focus) the cmd+shift+m mute hotkeys
function mutediscord()
    local discordapp = hs.application.find("Discord")
    -- print(discordapp)
    if discordapp ~= nil then
        -- print("Discord is open")
        hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(hs.keycodes.map.m, true):rawFlags(hs.eventtap.event.rawFlagMasks['command'] | hs.eventtap.event.rawFlagMasks['shift']):post(discordapp)
        hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(hs.keycodes.map.m, false):rawFlags(hs.eventtap.event.rawFlagMasks['command'] | hs.eventtap.event.rawFlagMasks['shift']):post(discordapp)
    -- else 
        -- print("discord is closed")
    end
end
--I used hidutil to flip the f5 and f6 keys
hs.hotkey.bind({}, "f5", mutediscord)

-- this function checks if discord is open, and if it is it sends it (while in the background or in focus) the cmd+shift+d deafen hotkeys
function deafendiscord()
    local discordapp = hs.application.find("Discord")
    -- print(discordapp)
    if discordapp ~= nil then
        -- print("Discord is open")
        hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(hs.keycodes.map.d, true):rawFlags(hs.eventtap.event.rawFlagMasks['command'] | hs.eventtap.event.rawFlagMasks['shift']):post(discordapp)
        hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(hs.keycodes.map.d, false):rawFlags(hs.eventtap.event.rawFlagMasks['command'] | hs.eventtap.event.rawFlagMasks['shift']):post(discordapp)
    -- else 
        -- print("discord is closed")
    end
end

hs.hotkey.bind({}, "f6", deafendiscord)

Pretty sure you need to reboot to make the hidutil stuff work. But now you can mute and unmute discord in the background using keyboard shortcuts. I imagine you could easily extend these to do something for multiple programs.
Sadly if your computer is locked you will need to unlock it to still mute yourself.

PS: Just wanted to add some sources that helped me figure this out.

https://rakhesh.com/mac/using-hidutil-to-map-macos-keyboard-keys/
https://www.nanoant.com/mac/macos-function-key-remapping-with-hidutil
https://mybyways.com/blog/remapping-physical-function-keys-on-macbook-pros
https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/

